# Opening existing project from source control

Tags: eclipse, mercurial

I've been pushing my source to a Mercurial repository.  Today I needed to delete my local copy and re-clone.  I did this by simply moving my local copy somewhere else (just in case) and typing "hg clone url".

This part has worked just fine.

However, when I try to pull the newly cloned local copy into Eclipse, I get the following error:

```
/Users/Andrew/Dev/Workspace/Android/MyProject overlaps the location of another project: 'MyProject'
```

My guess is that I have been committing some meta file or something that I shouldn't have.  Does anyone have any ideas?  Here is my .hgignore:

```
syntax: regexp
\.DS_Store
.swo
.swp
.metadata/
/bin/
```

Note: Looks like my hgignore is not blocking the gen folder.  Could this be part of the problem?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

There is a bug in Eclipse what won't let you create an Android project from existing sources:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8431

You have to move *MyProject* to a folder that doesn't have any other projects in its sub-directories.  You can then make a new project from existing source with *MyProject*.  Remove the new project from the workspace without deleting the contents on disk and move it back to your *Android* folder.  Now do an **Import -> General -> Existing Project into Workspace**, and *MyProject* should be available to import.

This is the only way I've been able to do it.

Comment: Thanks, this answer solved my problem too. It does not seem to be isolated to Android projects. I'm surprised the bug still exists.

Comment: Thanks, you saved me some time. Still have this bug today with Eclipse Juno and android tools 21

Comment: What would I do without Stack Overflow!  How long would it have taken me to figure this out on my own!?!  A heck of a long time!

Comment: @Nate I'm not surprised the bug still exists. I can lists a dozen bugs in Eclipse relating to Android development...

Answer (score 6):

Ok, I'll try to sum it up, after I faced similar problems and wasted some time:

Eclipse Juno /4.2 SR1 
(however I think it is a general misunderstanding of how eclipse imports projects)

1. If you want your new project "connected" to git/mercurial, you'll have to clone and import via "Import/Git/Import from Git"
2. It will fail if your "workspace dir" equals the "local destination dir".
   **A git clone via egit MUST NOT be placed! in the "eclipse workspace dir**"!

The project import will fail because the projectname in the cloned ".project file" already exists in the eclipse workspace dir when the import occurs.

Comment: This is the solution that worked for me. Import from git, instead of android.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you moved your local copy away and then you try to add another project into Eclipse at the same location as what you had before and you are just confusing Eclipse...

I would recommend to try to use command line commands for Mercurial and when you get into Eclipse, first clean up existing projects before adding another one.

Comment: I'm not so sure this is right.  I had a friend pull my source (who has never pulled it before) and he is having the same problem.  If he sets his Eclipse working directory to ../Dev/Workspace/Android, places the project there and tries to open it in Eclipse, he gets the same error.

Comment: Eclipse creates the files .project and .classpath and the folder .settings. Those are not needed by Android itself... maybe you can check that ?

Answer (score 0):

My sollution was just to import as `general` project not an `android` one.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem when trying to import a git repo project and it's submodules.  I ended up using import -> git -> Projects from Git (git plugin).  This understood the concept of a project within a project just fine. The project is now monitored by that plugin.  It's a good enough tradeoff for me.