# While importing project in eclipse workspace showing error invalid project description?

Tags: android

I have taken code from server repository in a folder in D drive. while i import project in workspace it shows error invalid project description ?what is solution of it.

Answer (score 15):

Your project location should not be the same as that of your current workspace location. Copy the project to some other location and try importing...make sure there is no folder with the same name exists in your current work space.

Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784652/eclipse-invalid-project-description-when-creating-new-project-from-existing-so) for more help.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a new Android project and select "Create from existing source" (the exact way of doing this is different depending on what version of ADT you have).

Answer (score 0):

You might be having another project in your workspace .. pointing to same location

Answer (score 0):

Take your project folder one directory lower or higher .

E.g. if your project folder path is : C:\ProjectFolder , then move it to something new like C:\NewFolder\ProjectFolder . 
Now import this ProjectFolder .Bingo.

Hope it helps..