# Using git command line for android projects in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, git

I've been trying to figure out how to use git without egit in eclipse.

I clone an existing android project on remote repository into my eclipse workspace. If this project directory is the root folder itself, I can't import this project with error, "Invalid project description". If I have one more folder on top of this project in the remote repository, it works when I clone and import into eclipse.

Former looks like  this...
workspace/myproject

and latter which works is...
workspace/topfolder/myproject

Am I importing this git repo the right way?

Then once I have the project set up on eclipse, I will set up .gitignore and I can start to modify, stage, commit, and push etc.

*** Update ***

To import into eclipse, I do the following.
First I go to my eclipse workspace.

`cd example/workspace`

Then, `git clone https://github.com/me/test.git`

I open eclipse and go to File > New > Project > Android Project from Existing Code. I select the directory cloned. I leave the "copy into directory" unchecked because I want to use cloned git.

When I do this, I get "Invalid project description" for having a directory of same name which is the cloned folder itself.

If I put this cloned folder in another folder, it works. I just have a feeling that this might not be the correct way or how everyone does.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git for beginners: The definitive practical guide](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/315911/git-for-beginners-the-definitive-practical-guide)

Comment: I looked through your link and I could not find an answer to my issue. Could you point out where in that link this issue is stated?

Comment: How do you import project into workspace? There should be no problems like this with regular Project Import wizard.

Comment: I edited the question to explain what I do. I want to import together with the git, so I can modify, add, commit, and so on to it.

Comment: @RC this sounds like an eclipse problem rather than a git problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I set up my projects. This is a common problem as seen here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5784712/1619929

Comment: This is helpful. The solution was to import project as general project instead of android project. Thanks.